# SQL 2008 tables transfer

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two different database with different tables in the same SQL 2008.

1. Access Control DB with 5000 Employee.
2. TimeTrack DB.

How can I transfer the complete from Access Control DB to TimeTrack DB.
Please see attached tables.
Thanks and Best Regards.
Muhsin Jiwari
Baghdad - Iraq

1- [Access Control].[dbo].[TEmployee] Tables.

Comment: Are you trying to just copy all the tables into `TimeTrack` ?

Comment: do the tables have the same structure? you haven't included any details on the structures.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast response - I am trying to send you the tables.

Comment: If you want to export the datas from access control db to time track  with the same table structure you can use data import export in sql server